# Automatic change of activity : Landscape and portrait mode in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, landscape

I have two activities in my Android app. On click I can move from one activity to another, back and forth. But when I am changing from landscape to portrait mode and vice versa, my activity is getting changed automatically which I did not expect. I expect it to remain on the same activity even if it is changed to portrait or landscape mode. So what might be the problem?

**Update**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dmacs.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon1"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/icon2"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity android:name=".second_main">
        </activity><!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
     App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you show your code? Normally, changing landscape and potrait do not change your activity.

Comment: I have added the manifest. @Polarbear0106

Comment: @Joshua Which part of the code you want me to display?

Comment: @Sanik You activities classes.

Comment: Show your activity class code

Comment: I am not able to post the code..format error

Comment: I have posted the second activity code @Vickyexpert

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="sensor" 
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I simply added this line: `android:screenOrientation="sensor"`

It overrides the system(if your system can lock orientation)

Also add this line: `android:configChanges="orientation"`

It prevents any updates from occuring triggered by the orientation